# Calculate 7 day percentage change by category in custom SQL query for Amazon Quicksight

Tags: sql, amazon-quicksight

I am using Amazon Quicksight to visualize music streaming data. I currently have a number of custom queries that look at the data supplied by a streaming service and categorizes their source  classifications into our own source categories.

We then visualize that data in Quicksight to show the amount of streams generated by each source category over time.

I would now like to add the ability to show the 7 day percentage change in a column for each category, but am stumped on how to do that.

Here is the query that I am using to categorize the streams (with some name changes):

```
(SELECT
    count(*) as streams,
    internal.isrc_map.isrc as isrc,
    service.streams.country as country,
    service.source as original_source,
CASE
        WHEN service.streams.source = 'radio' THEN 'Category 1'
        WHEN service.streams.source IN ('queue', 'other') THEN 'Category 2'
        WHEN service.streams.source = 'collection' THEN 'Category 3'
        WHEN service.streams.source IN ('release', 'search', 'artist') THEN 'Category 4'
        WHEN service.streams.source = 'top20' THEN 'Category 5'
        WHEN service.streams.source = 'others' AND service.streams.source_url = '' THEN 'Category 5' 
        WHEN service.streams.source = 'others' AND service.streams.source_url LIKE '%playlist%' THEN 'Category 5'
        WHEN service.streams.source = 'others' AND service.streams.source_url != '' AND service.streams.source_url NOT LIKE '%playlist%'  THEN 'Category 1'
        ELSE 'Unidentified'
    END as source,
    service.streams.a_data_date as date
FROM
    service.streams
JOIN service.tracks ON
    service.streams.track_id = service.tracks.track_id
JOIN internal.isrc_map ON
    internal.isrc_map.isrc = service.tracks.isrc
WHERE
    client_id = 'client23'
GROUP BY
    service.streams.a_data_date,
    internal.isrc_map.isrc,
    service.streams.country,
    service.streams.source_url,
    service.streams.source
ORDER BY
    internal.isrc_map.isrc,
    service.streams.a_data_date)
```

I am very much a novice when it comes to sql queries. I tried to get a simple percentage change on total streams but keep receiving syntax errors in Quicksight and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is an example:

```
WITH last_7_days AS (
  SELECT 
    count(*) as streams, 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', service.streams.a_data_date) as date
  FROM 
    service.streams
  WHERE 
    date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  GROUP BY date
)
prev_7_days AS (
  SELECT 
    count(*) as streams, 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', service.streams.a_data_date) as date
  FROM 
    service.streams
  WHERE 
    date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
    AND date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  GROUP BY 
    date
) SELECT 
  last_7_days.streams,
  last_7_days.streams / prev_7_days.streams - 1 as pct_change
FROM 
  last_7_days
```

Producing this error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "7" Position: 192

Comment: You'll need a comma between the two CTEs above. And then `from last_7_days cross join prev_y_days` to bring in both tables at the bottom.

Comment: If you can guarantee there are no gaps in the dates then a simple `lag()` should get you back seven days.

Comment: One approach as pseudo-code: `with data as (<your query for all relevant dates>) select * from data as d1 left outer join data as d2 on d2.source = d1.source and d2.data_date = date_sub(d1.data_date, interval 7 days)`